# TYPO3 8: sys_language_overlay in free translation mode

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

when a page is translated in free mode - or copy mode - i do have problems with

```
config.sys_language_overlay
```

- set to 0 works: this shows all content elements with language id of the foreign language
- set to 1 does not work: this shows only the content elements of the default language (remember: free mode - there is no overlay) The elements with the language id of the foreign language are hidden.
- set to "hideNonTranlated" does not work: this shows nothing because there are no Overlay-Records in free mode.

So i should set it to 0 which is mentioned in the manual: "This boils down to “free mode” language handling".

BUT:

My editors mix the mode from page to page and so we got many pages in free mode and many others in translated mode.

```
config.sys_language_overlay = 0
```

works well in free mode but shows nothing in connected mode.

```
config.sys_language_overlay = 1
```

works well in connected mode but shows only the default language in translation.

```
config.sys_language_overlay = hideNonTranslated
```

works only in connected mode and shows nothing in free mode.

I found no possibility to change this configuration depending on the translation mode of the actual page. And the editors cannot change it too.

Any idea how to fix this broken behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There exist many issues concerning translation handling in TYPO3, here is a list of a few of them:

- https://forge.typo3.org/issues/19114
- https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86595
- https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86762
- https://forge.typo3.org/issues/87121
- https://forge.typo3.org/issues/88137

The best is to add info to existing issues or create new ones. Also testing and commenting on fixes for issues can help, as test-cases often are limited and not satisfying every use-case.